# Configure port number of ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using ElasticSearch 0.20.2 and run the daemon using

> bin/elasticsearch [-f]

The bin/elasticsearch script sets ES_HOME on its own and there seem to be no way
to influence the path of the configuration file read. ES always reads the settings from

> $ES_HOME/config/elasticsearch.yml

However I must be able for specifying the path to our own configuration file **without**
overriding the existing **elasticsearch.yml** that comes with ElasticSearch.

How do I do that?

Comment: Have you [checked the docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/setup/configuration.html)?

Answer (score 42):

You have to insert following line in your `elasticsearch.yml` file.

```
http.port: port_number
```

I did same in my setup, its working for me.

Answer (score 19):

For multi-version testing, you should specify two different ports:

```
bin/elasticsearch -E http.port=9400 -E transport.tcp.port=9500
```

This way, if you have another version of elasticsearch on the same machine, they won't talk to each other.  If you do want them to communicate, leave the transport port as default, or make it the same on both instances.

Answer (score 7):

Just change the `http.port` in `elasticsearch.yml` (commonly in `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`) and  remove # from the front and restart your server.

Answer (score 5):

You need to modify `path.conf`.  It would look like:

```
bin/elasticsearch -f -Des.path.conf=/path/to/config/dir
```

That will then read `/path/to/config/dir/elasticsearch.yml` and `/path/to/config/dir/elasticsearch.json` (if present).

Also keep in mind that you can just specify any option you'd like via `-Des.` in the same way I did with `path.conf` above.

Comment: The `-Des.http.port=XXX` trick here is rather useful for testing a cluster locally with the same settings but different ports.

Comment: Also note that this switch syntax will change to `-E http.port=XXX` in 5.0+.

Answer (score 1):

you can always set it up externally while starting elasticsearch:

```
$ elasticsearch -f -Des.config=<NewConfig>
```