# How to map elasticsearch port from 9200 to 92xx when running in kibana with docker-compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I have a docker-compose.yaml file with elasticsearch and kibana defined.

When I run docker-compose, I will be able to access kibana with the url http://localhost:8181 with everything running as exepcted. However, my issue is that I do not want to use elasticsearch port 9200 in kibana, I want to use another port (ex. 9201)

How can I make elasticsearch connect in kibana while using a port different than 9200?

I have tried adding the following below but I get an error 
"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9201."

```
elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.2.3
    environment:
        discovery.type: single-node
    ports:
        -"9201:9200"

kibana:
    depends_on:
        - elasticsearch
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana-oss:6.2.3
    environment:
        SERVER_NAME: "s_name"
        ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9201
    ports:
        - "8181:5601"
```

The below works fine with port 9200

```
elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.2.3
    environment:
      discovery.type: single-node

kibana:
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana-oss:6.2.3
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: "s_name"
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200
    ports:
      - "8181:5601"
```

Comment: Hi, could you please tell us what was the final solution? I am facing the same issue here

Comment: thanks, I got it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9201`

Set this to `ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200` instead.

`"9201:9200"` maps from container port to host port. That is, it exposes 9201 on your host's network interfaces, and forwards it to port 9200 in the container.

Your Kibana service however, was trying to connect to 9201 of `elasticsearch` - a *different* container on a different network w/ a different IP address, not 127.0.0.1, and in that network, the container is running a process on port 9200.

EDIT: reading again, you can configure the port [Configure port number of ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379575/configure-port-number-of-elasticsearch). Try setting `http.port` in the environment (based on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-configuration-methods):

`elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.2.3
    environment:
        discovery.type: single-node
        http.port: 9201-9301
    ports:
        -"9201:9201"`

Comment: In this case, I have 2 instances of elasticsearch and kibana running and I want both to work when accessing kibana from localhost. Changing the port did not solve the issue, but it allowed one service to work. Any possible solutions for making both work when using docker-compose

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not solve the issue, but it allowed one service to work" ?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is that I have 2 services. In these 2 services I have docker-compose.yaml file. When I bring them both up, elasticsearch does not work in kibana. I thought changing the port numbers for elasticsearch would solve the issue. What could be the solution for it?

Comment: Can I have a look at your `docker-compose.yaml` file with both the services, and Kibana? Assuming you are running one of the ES on a different port, and you modified Kibana to connect to that ES on that specific port, you shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: The first one is the same, instead of 9202 I used 9201. 
elasticsearch_1:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.2.3
    restart: always
    environment:
      discovery.type: single-node
      http.port: 9202
    volumes:
      - "./storage/elastic-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
    ports:
      - "9202:9202"

  kibana_1:
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch_1
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana-oss:6.2.3
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: "s_name1"
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch_1:9202
    ports:
      - "8191:5601"

Comment: Can you check the logs of `elasticsearch_1`, and of `kibana_1` ? Run `docker-compose logs <service>`.

Comment: kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-12-25T13:10:27Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch_1:9202/"}
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-12-25T13:10:27Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}

Comment: elasticsearch_1  | [2018-12-25T13:08:12,645][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
elasticsearch_1  | [2018-12-25T13:08:12,750][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [DV0vu9b] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (overlay)]], net usable_space [52.2gb], net total_space [58.4gb], types [overlay]
elasticsearch_1  | [2018-12-25T13:08:12,750][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [DV0vu9b] heap size [989.8mb],compressed ordinary object pointers [true]

Comment: This is what I get when I run docker-compose logs for these services

Comment: @CEJ This is the Docker Compose I used, and it appears to work https://gist.github.com/MrSaints/35e3735affebb3da97b25a35e418236d

Comment: It works while running multiple instances. I had to though change the memory to 4GB under docker -> preferences -> advanced

Comment: Thank you, I got it working and I just want to mention one thing ```ELASTICSEARCH_URL``` that you used in docker-compose.yml (Github) is deprecated in Elasticsearch 6.8.x and it should be ```ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS```.